# Ignore all lint warnings errors by package

Tags: android, lint

I want to ignore every lint warning and error in the entire `com` package.

From the [lint documentation](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings) I can only see how I can ignore certain issues for specific files and directories using `path` and `regexp`.

How can I ignore every issue in the `com` package?

Answer (score 1):

So try this :

```
   <lint>
       <issue id="InvalidPackage">
          <ignore regexp="com.*" />
      </issue>
   </lint>
```

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I have to specify the issue, I want all issues to be ignored in `com.*`

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore all the lint warnings using `id="all"`, the following example is from the lint report itself:

```
<!-- Ignore everything in the test source set -->
<issue id="all">
    <ignore path="*/test/*" />
</issue>
```

so in your case it would be very close to @MrZ's response:

```
    <issue id="all">
        <ignore regexp="com.*" />
    </issue>
```

Answer (score -4):

try to use the following

```
-keep class com.example.** {
    public protected private *;
 }
-dontwarn com.example.**
```

Comment: That's proguard and has nothing to do with lint

Comment: I'm sorry to go fast